# setting a string into long[] for vibrate function

Tags: java, android

i am doing a application to do custom vibrations based on the characters in a text file but am facing problem dealing with passing in a custom vibration through a method

```
private void classifier(char c)
{
    String s = null;

    if (c == 'L')
    {
        s = "{0, dot, long_gap, long_gap, short_gap, dot, medium_gap}";
    }
    vibratePattern(s);
}

private void vibratePattern(String s)
{
    Vibrator vibrator;
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    long[] pattern101 = s;
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern101, -1);
}
```

what am i trying to get here is that when the classifier method detects a char "L" passed in when using the classifier method it will pass in the pattern to the vibratePattern method to process and proceed with the vibration

i know that my code here is wrong as i am using a string in the classifier method while the vibrate method takes in a long[]

i tried using parseLong to convert the string to long but the long[] does not accept it..

Comment: You shoud check the example again, from which you copied this piece of code. There is clearly no String involved, just a array of long constants.

Comment: thanks i came up with the codes myself got my answer already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a method needs a `long[]` as argument, give it a `long[]`, not a String :

```
private void classifier(char c)
{
    long[] s = null;

    if (c == 'L')
    {
        s = new long[] {0, dot, long_gap, long_gap, short_gap, dot, medium_gap};
    }
    vibratePattern(s);
}

private void vibratePattern(long[] s)
{
    Vibrator vibrator;
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    vibrator.vibrate(s, -1);
}
```

Comment: is it possible for me to add in the pattern on the go. right now this is only 1 pattern right.. but what if i have like 20 patterns? how do i put all of them into the long[]